# Using cd command to navigate directories in Ubuntu which have special characters

Tags: command-line, bash, filesystem

When I want to navigate into directories having special characters in their names I get an error message.

For example:

```
aman@desktop:~/Aman$ cd !)e$!gn&(reate
bash: !: event not found
aman@desktop:~/Aman$
```

Here `!)e$!gn&(reate` is the directory name where I want to navigate.

How to rectify this error?

How to use `cd` command to navigate directories in Ubuntu having directory name with special characters?

Comment: You can turn off history expansion: `set +H` -- turn it back on with `set -H`

Answer (score 19):

That error is happening because the `!` (bang) is a shortcut that allows you re-run a command from your history.  Ex: This command re-runs command #1504 from my history.

```
$ !1504
```

To avoid that issue, try encapsulating your directory name with single quotes.

```
$ cd '!)e$!gn&(reate'
```

That being said, while Ubuntu (Linux) will let you name directories in this way, I would highly recommend against it.  Using special characters in directory names can make them difficult to read, and if you are using a reserved character you will always need to escape it or encapsulate the directory name in quotes.

Comment: +1 especially for the last paragraph... and if they can avoid spaces too, will be grateful in the future. Just MHO.

Comment: @Rmano Yes, I'm with you on that.  Spaces in directory/file names drive me crazy.

Comment: `set +H` or `set +o histexpand` to disable the special treatment of `!`. Add that to your `~/.bash_profile` or even some system-wide config file and you'll have one less thing to worry about. Unless you are actually using this feature, that is.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is called, but I call it "passing the file name as a string" since that is what it would be called in programming.

Answer (score 10):

You use `\` before special characters

```
cd \!\)e\$\!gn\&\(reate
```

You can also put entire foldername in single quotes

```
cd '!)e$!gn&(reate'
```

You can encapsulate entire path within single quotes

```
cd 'Desktop/!)e$!gn&(reate'
```

if you want to refer a path inside /home/username directory: just add `~/` before path in single quotes

```
cd ~/'Desktop/!)e$!gn&(reate'
```

Answer (score 5):

Interactively, type `cd !` then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and bash will fill in the rest, properly escaped.

Comment: Will that work even if the first character is a special character, or will you have to type `cd \!` then `TAB`?

Comment: works for me without escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this applies to special characters, but perhaps put the path inside double quotes?

Comment: Double quotes will help with special characters like spaces that aren't interpolated, but won't help with $, ! and the like, which are interpolated. There are two types of strings in bash: double quotes, which allow for interpolation, and single quotes, which don't. (This is why you should always put your regex for `grep`, `sed`, etc. in single quotes.)

Answer (score 2):

Confirming @glenn jackman's answer works in practise, I typed `cd !` and then pressed [tab]

`ianh@abe:~/tmp$ mkdir '!)e$!gn&(reate'
ianh@abe:~/tmp$ cd \!\)e\$\!gn\&\(reate/
ianh@abe:~/tmp/!)e$!gn&(reate$`

Even making a directory with '!1997' and typing `cd !1` and then pressing [tab] worked.

`ianh@abe:~/tmp/!)e$!gn&(reate$ mkdir '!1997'
ianh@abe:~/tmp/!)e$!gn&(reate$ cd \!1997/
ianh@abe:.../!)e$!gn&(reate/!1997$`

(i dont have enough rep points to add it as a comment)