# cd to a directory has hash (#)

Tags: command-line

Well, I have few directories have name contains hashes (#, eg: #abczxy).
Now I can't to execute this `cd #foo` it will redirect me back to the root directory equal with this command `cd`

The question is, is this possible to do that or is there any tricks allow me do that?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change directory to a folder with special characters?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101587/how-do-i-change-directory-to-a-folder-with-special-characters) And also duplicate of [Using cd command to navigate directories in Ubuntu which have special characters](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453770/using-cd-command-to-navigate-directories-in-ubuntu-which-have-special-characters?lq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote the directory name:

```
$ cd '#foo'
```

Or escape it using a backslash:

```
$ cd \#foo
$ cd bar#  #works
```

The second one works since a comment at the end of the line must have [whitespace before `#`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html).

Or give the full path:

```
$ cd ./#foo
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [@muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/543243/323845), you can disable bash [interactive_comments](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Comments.html) option:

```
shopt -u interactive_comments
```

Now, you can `cd` to a directory start with `#` normally:

```
$ cuonglm at /tmp
$ cd #asd
$ cuonglm at /tmp/#asd
$ pwd
/tmp/#asd
```